# Hibernate Exception: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate

Plz help me as soon as possible.I am also getting same exception when i am using a filter to close the session.Previously i was closing session in every methods but currently i am closing session using filter.I am getting this exception any time when saveOrupdate method is called or not also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked with session.Merge()

Answer (score 1):

Using session.Merge() method will resolve your problem. check it and let me know.